# Trying to marshall (C++ to C#) a message listener with callbacks

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm trying to marshall the following C++ code to C#. I have a `AddMessageListener` where:

> /** This function is used to register a listener for the messages.
>
> - nConId is Connection Identifier
> - pCallBack is a pointer to a function of type \ref MsgListenerCallBack
> - pUserData is a general purpose pointer; when a new messagge happens the callback is called with the same pointed data.
> - @return Number of message listener actives after the last function call
> - @retval >=1 The function succesfully added a new listener and returns the number of currently active listeners.
> - @retval <=0 The function failed in adding the new listener
>     */

```
extern "C" MY_API int AddMessageListener(const ConnectionId_T nConId, MsgListenerCallBack pCallBack, void *pUserData);
```

... and a pointer to a callback function:

> /** 
>   * Pointer to a callback function used when a new message is generated.
>
> - MsgListenerCallBack is a pointer to a function that takes one char * and a  void * as input.
> - The first char * is the generated message, the second is a general purpose void * .
> - **Example**: void OnMessage(const char pMessage, void *pUserData) @endverbatim
> - @see AddMessageListener()
>     */

```
typedef void (*MsgListenerCallBack)(const char *,void *);
```

The C++ code calls it as follows:

```
# nConId is returned from another function and the his value is 0
const int nAddMsgList(AddMessageListener(nConId, OnMessage,(void *)10));
printf("RETURNED TAG OF MESSAGE LISTENERS: %d\n",nAddMsgList);
```

This uses the function `OnMessage`:

```
void OnMessage(const char *pMsg,void *pUserData)
{
    int nMyData=(int)pUserData;
    printf("MSG:%s DATA:%d\n",pMsg,nMyData);
}
```

So, my try to marshall the `AddMessageListener` is:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AddMessageListener(ConnectionId_T pConId, MsgListenerCallBack pCallBack, IntPtr pUserData);
```

And the `OnMessage`:

```
void OnMessage(string pMsg, IntPtr pUserData)
{
     int nMyData=(int)pUserData;
     Console.Write("MSG:%s DATA:%d\n",pMsg,nMyData);
}
```

The problem is that I dont know how to marshall `typedef void (*MsgListenerCallBack)(const char *,void *);`. Can someone give me a hand? Plus, the two marshall I already done (`AddMessageListener` and `OnMessage`) are correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15481130/17034

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Im quite new at marshalling and this is the most complicated task I've ever done in C#. The `typedef void (*MsgListenerCallBack)(const char *,void *);` should be `public delegate void MsgListenerCallBack(X, Y);`. But which are the values of `X` and `Y`? `const char *` should be a `string`? And `void *`? Thanks.

Comment: You already got that.  You cannot ignore the attribute.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: I already tried all that I've done in the post, plus the comment answer, But I dont know how to marshall the arguments `(const char *,void *)` of `MsgListenerCallBack`.